# Can we have porn link prevention implemented here?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, links

Mechanism is ready: [Help users create dummy links that are not to unrelated commercial sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186529/225745) has [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Could it be implemented here on Drupal Answers too?

I just encountered a question that links to one of these porn sites. From my workplace. Our firewall registered it. I may be in trouble.

Comment: Can you flag the post so I can take care of it?

Comment: @MPD Not really, now I can't even open any page containing it. Should be on top of this list: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=xxx.com but my concern is more general - I don't want to be afraid every time I click something on the frontpage. And I might be unable to open *this* page once I will post this comment - not sure, as here bad address is a part of another URL.

Comment: I edited a few of them.  Anyone else reading this is encouraged to use this search and change the links to example.com

Comment: We're officially porn free, cleared up the last few yesterday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done. Note that this blocks edits to old posts as well as new ones, so you may find the occasional prompt to rework a link when editing.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this.